# Parse output from json python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a json below, and I want to parse out value from this dict.

I can do something like this to get one specific value

```
print(abc['everything']['A']['1']['tree']['value'])
```

But, what is best way to parse out all "value?"
I want to output good, bad, good.

```
   abc = {'everything': {'A': {'1': {'tree': {'value': 'good'}}}, 

'B': {'5': {'tree1': {'value': 'bad'}}},

'C': {'30': {'tree2': {'value': 'good'}}}}}
```

Comment: That's not JSON, that's regular Python dictionaries.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If they are consistent, you can loop through the first key of each nested dictionary until you get one with key `value` then return its value, repeat.

Comment: like larry said just loop through each, check if value is not a dictionary type -> you get the results

Comment: This is dirty 1-liner if your structure is consistent `[v[0][0][0] for v in [[[list(l3.values()) for l3 in l2.values()] for l2 in l1.values()] for l1 in abc['everything'].values()]]`

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use `pandas`, you could just use `pd.json_normalize`, which is actually quite fast:

```py
import pandas as pd
 
abc = {'everything': {'A': {'1': {'tree': {'value': 'good'}}}, 

'B': {'5': {'tree1': {'value': 'bad'}}},

'C': {'30': {'tree2': {'value': 'good'}}}}}

df = pd.json_normalize(abc)
print(df.values[0])
```

```
['good' 'bad' 'good']
```

Without any extra libraries, you will have to iterate through your nested dictionary:

```py
values = [abc['everything'][e][k][k1]['value'] for e in abc['everything'] for k in abc['everything'][e] for k1 in abc['everything'][e][k]]
print(values)
```

```
['good', 'bad', 'good']
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided your keys and dictionaries have a `value` somewhere, you can try this:

- Create a function (or reuse the code) that gets the first element of the dictionary until the `value` key exists, then return that. Note that there are other ways of doing this.
- Iterate through, getting the result under each `value` key and return.

```
# Define function
def get(d):
    while not "value" in d:
        d = list(d.values())[0]
    return d["value"]

# Get the results from your example
results = [get(v) for v in list(abc["everything"].values())]
```

```
['good', 'bad', 'good']
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the syntax you are using is incorrect.

If you are using pandas, you can code like

import pandas as pd

df4 = pd.DataFrame({"TreeType": ["Tree1", "Tree2", "Tree3"],
"Values": ["Good", "Bad","Good"]})

df4.index = ["A","B","C"]

next just run the code df4, you would get the correct output.

output:

```
TreeType    Values
```

A   Tree1        Good
B   Tree2        Bad
C   Tree3        Good

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).